# What happens when an Enlarged Creature dies?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, creature-size, objects, duration

*Enlarge* says it works on both creatures and objects. The spell doesn't specify what happens when a creature dies and the way I understand it is that a living, breathing creature becomes an object when it dies since objects are neither living, nor breathing.

So does the creature become a new object of the size it originally had or does the object carry over the *Enlarge* status of the creature and within the minute returns to normal size?

I can see both things happening, within reason. What I'm looking to do is *Enlarge* a critter, kill it, and take it back to our hosts to eat, so I'm wondering what would happen en route to the cooking pot.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Alive or dead, it stays enlarged for the duration of the spell.

Unless otherwise stated, a spell lasts for its duration.

The only rule that covers general [spell duration](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/spellcasting#Duration) is a small section on page 203 of the *PHB*:

> **A spell's duration is the length of time the spell persists.** A duration can be expressed in rounds, minutes, hours, or even years. Some spells specify that their effects last until the spells are dispelled or destroyed.

And the rules that cover monster death aren't very extensive either. Page 7 of the *Monster Manual* says, under ["Hit Points"](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/monsters#HitPoints):

> A monster usually dies or is destroyed when it drops to 0 hit points. For more on hit points, see the *Player's Handbook*.

And *PHB* page 198 says, under ["Monsters and Death"](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#MonstersandDeath):

> Most DMs have a monster die the instant it drops to 0 hit points, rather than having it fall unconscious and make death saving throws. Mighty villains and special nonplayer characters are common exceptions; the DM might have them fall unconscious and follow the same rules as player characters.

Other than that, there's no *specific* rule that says spell effects end on a creature when it dies, unless the creature is the one casting and the spell requires concentration (*PHB*, p. 203), so they *should* carry on (exceptions might be made at the DM's discretion).

Thus, **the creature would stay *enlarged* for the full 1-minute duration of the spell, whether dead or alive, unless your concentration is broken.**