# Can banishment affect dead bodies?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

One of my players cast the banishment spell on a dead body. I wasn't sure in the moment if this actually worked, and so I said it didn't. Can someone tell if it does or does not and why?

Comment: Do you want to explain why/why not?

Comment: At least a bit of explanation would be nice.

Comment: I can see the confusion... I should have worded it differently. I meant could you add into your question *your* reasoning for why or why not?

Comment: What "dead bodies"? Do you mean undead?

Comment: Did they try to hide a corpse that way?

Comment: @Feldragoon could you elaborate the question a little? In the title you ask if banishment can be cast, but in the body you ask if it "works" (how exactly do you suppose it works?). It might be better to ask what happens when you do this, or is it possible to achieve a certain result.

Comment: Thanks for asking me to clarify the question. Hopefully this ends up being more helpful.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, the *banishment* spell would not work on a corpse. *Banishment* targets creatures:

> You
>   attempt
>   to
>   send
>   one
>   creature
>   that
>   you
>   can
>   see
>   within
>   range
>   to
>   another
>   plane
>   of
>   existence.

And [corpses are objects, not creatures](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/55951/15469).

Comment: It wouldn't work, that does not automatically mean you can't cast it.

Comment: @enkryptor True, but to cast a spell you have to choose a valid target, and a corpse isn't a valid target for *banishment*.

Comment: You still can waste a spell on an incorrect target. Say, casting Polymorph on a shapechanger. (or do you imply the caster automatically knows if the target is a shapechanger)

Comment: @enkryptor No, but a shapechanger is a valid target for polymorph. Polymorph can be cast on any creature. A shapechanger automatically makes their saving throw, but they're still valid targets.

Comment: So, if the object is an image of a creature, you can't target it with a spell like Sacred Flame? Does that mean the caster automatically reveals illusions?

Comment: @enkryptor Good question - I'd suggest asking it as its own question.

Comment: The intention when casting a spell with an illegal target is that it still takes up the casting time to do so, but the spell has no effect and the slot is not expended (if >= level 1). This is not written anywhere but was clarified as the intent during the Sage Advice segment of [this Dragon Talk](http://dnd.wizards.com/articles/features/wolfgang-baur-girl-scouts-midgard).

Comment: @enkryptor If you do pose that question link it here because I'm curious as well.

Comment: @EthanTheBrave http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/96327/