# Can two creatures cooperate to carry a third to avoid the speed penalty?

Tags: dnd-5e, encumbrance

A player and I wanted to carry a third unconscious creature between both (so we could avoid applying the "Push, drag or lift" rules and move 30 feet as normal). As I have 60 pounds left to carry and my teammate has 135 pounds left, we should be able to carry the third player (who weighs 180 pounds including inventory and himself).

The point of the question is, is this possible? Can we cooperate to "share" the third player's weight and still have a 30 feet movement speed?

Note: Following Standard encumbrance rules (thanks to @slagmoth and @nautarch for remembering me to add this).

Comment: Might be important to disclose which encumbrance rules you are using. Standard or Variant.

Comment: Related on [What are the rules around picking up and carrying bodies?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/103496/what-are-the-rules-around-picking-up-and-carrying-bodies)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Ask your DM

Unfortunately, given your [previous question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/125691/grappling-an-ally) on grappling an ally, it is going to come back to how your DM rules with regard to grappling (or not grappling).

### You've got a friend

Once the DM has determined how they rule on picking up an unconscious creature, they will need to consider how the [Help](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/basic-rules/combat#Help) action would work (as this is our mechanic for having an ally assist with a task.) Whether this would give advantage on the Grapple, or split the weight, or require the use of both hands for each character and not just 1 will be up to the DM to decide.

### So heavy

Once that has all been determined, you will also need to look at the encumbrance rules your table follows and how that may change the interaction with the unconscious/willing creature.