# Can you use Sending on a dead creature?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, planes, targeting

So I'm playing a D&D 5e campaign and my character is a 8th level cleric. One of the 3rd level cleric spells is *sending.* It states:

> You send a short message of twenty-five words or less to a creature with you are familiar. The creature hears the message in its mind, recognizes you as the sender if it knows you, and can answer in a like manner immediately. The spell enables creatures with Intelligence scores of at least 1 to understand the meaning of your message.

And *speak with dead,* which is 3rd level, states:

> Until the spell ends, you can ask the corpse up to five questions. The corpse knows only what it knew in life, including the languages it knew. Answers are usually brief, cryptic, or repetitive, and the corpse is under no compulsion to offer a truthful answer if you are hostile to it or it recognizes you as an enemy.

Do a creature's soul and spirit go to a different plane so I can use *sending* on them? The spell has unlimited range and only requires target to have a mind to understand, but only has 25 words limited so you can ask about 2-3 questions, and the spell *speak with dead* allows you to ask 5 questions. Good thing with *sending* is that you don't need a body nearby. Is this balanced? Could it be done?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Sending requires targeting a creature. [A dead body is considered an object, not a creature](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/55951/is-a-dead-creatures-body-considered-an-object), so sending would not work on a corpse.

You could try to target the soul of the creature instead. I cannot find any rules as to whether a soul counts as a creature.

As to whether the soul travels to a different plane: It appears so:

Monster Manual (p203):

> Doing so binds the soul to the mortal world, preventing it from traveling to the Outer Planes after death.