# Can you use the Dimension Door spell to teleport while carrying a dead body?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, teleportation

The description of the [*Dimension Door*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/dimension-door) spell includes:

> You can bring along objects as long as their weight doesn’t exceed what you can carry. You can also bring one willing creature of your size or smaller who is carrying gear up to its carrying capacity.

My example of this is: a villain kills one of the good NPCs. Can that villain take the body with them through a *Dimension Door* spell?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already and see the [help] or ask us here in the comments (use @ to ping someone) if you need more guidance. Good Luck and Happy Gaming!

Comment: Does this question/answer "[Is a dead creature's body considered an "object"](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/55951)" answer your question?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## It depends on the bulk of the NPC and the beefiness of your villain

[A corpse is considered an object](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/55951/52137). Therefore the relevant part of the spell is:

> You can bring along objects as long as their weight doesn’t exceed what you can carry.

So if the villain can carry the NPC corpse, it can be brought through.

Suggested weight of different races can be found on page 121 of the *Player's Handbook*. It gives the average weight of a human as 165 lb. which is within the carrying capacity of a medium (or small) creature with a Strength of 11 (all gear, both villans and NPCs, ignored).