# Can a level 1 genie patron warlock casting genie's vessel bring in a corpse?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, warlock

As a Warlock with a Genie patron, I have access to Geneie's vessel. I'm wondering if I can store a dead party member in it. I'm looking for a way to bring dead party members home.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Is this also an AL question?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### As long as a corpse is an object this works

[This question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/55951/33161) goes into more detail whether or not a corpse is an object. As long as the answer to that is yes this plan should work. The Genie’s Vessel feature Bottled Respite states the following:

> As an action, you can magically vanish and enter your vessel, which
> remains in the space you left. The interior of the vessel is an
> extradimensional space in the shape of a 20-foot-radius cylinder, 20
> feet high, and resembles your vessel. The interior is appointed with
> cushions and low tables and is a comfortable temperature. While
> inside, you can hear the area around your vessel as if you were in its
> space. You can remain inside the vessel up to a number of hours equal
> to twice your proficiency bonus. You exit the vessel early if you use
> a bonus action to leave, if you die, or if the vessel is destroyed.
> When you exit the vessel, you appear in the unoccupied space closest
> to it. **Any objects left in the vessel remain there until carried out,
> and if the vessel is destroyed, every object stored there harmlessly
> appears in the unoccupied spaces closest to the vessel's former space.**
> Once you enter the vessel, you can't enter again until you finish a
> long rest.

The description states objects can be left behind so as long as the corpse can be treated as an object this should work as written.